# ESC/POS thermal printer. Printing an image via android app

Tags: android, escpos

How could we print an image/bitmap using android app. Until now i am able to print the texts.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the printer. Nobody else is going to be able to help you, particularly since we do not know what the printer is.

Comment: So is it printer dependent ?? Or dont we have particular set of common commands for the these type of printer. 
PS: mine is some chinese printer bought from a local vendor !

Answer (score 1):

Try with this 
https://github.com/imrankst1221/Thermal-Printer-in-Android

It uses an deprecated command (as i read on another website) it doesnt print images above 250pixels, but its the best code so far.